# LIKE operator with a variable number of search conditions, in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, search-engine, sql-like

Is there a short way to look for multiple matches with the LIKE operator, using AND clauses?

I should do it dynamically, with a variable number of terms. Obtaining it statically (with a fixed number of terms) is a no-brainer:

```
 SELECT *
 from MyTable
 WHERE MyColumn LIKE "%AAA%"
    AND MyColumn LIKE "%BBB%"
    AND MyColumn LIKE "%CCC%"
```

Let's assume there is a table variable that contains an unknown number of terms:

```
DECLARE @Terms table
        (
        Term nvarchar(500)
        )
```

Is there a way to perform the LIKE statement on MyColumn matching all the items in @Terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a3d8/4/0):

```
select mt.*
  from MyTable mt
  join @Terms t
    on mt.MyColumn like '%' + t.Term + '%'
 group by mt.MyColumn
having COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from @Terms)
```

Comment: **@Blam**, you forgot the wildcards around `Term`.

Comment: I am assuming the Terms the wildcard.  But either way.

Comment: @Linger I don't agree the edit on the @.  The stated question is table variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @Terms TABLE
(
    WildCards VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Terms
( WildCards )
VALUES
( 'CO' ),
( 'DO' ),
( 'EO' )

DECLARE @FoundAll INT
SELECT @FoundAll = Count(*) FROM @Terms

SELECT mt.MyColumn, COUNT(*), @FoundAll FROM MyTable mt
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT WildCards FROM @Terms
) d
WHERE mt.MyColumn LIKE ('%' + d.WildCards + '%')
GROUP BY mt.MyColumn
HAVING COUNT(*) = @FoundAll
```

This will only pull the record which matches ALL of the possible likes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with not using the `LIKE` then the following would work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyColumn IN
(
  SELECT Term 
  FROM Terms
)
```

Or, how about the following ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cbed/1/0)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN Terms 
  ON MyTable.MyColumn LIKE '%' + Terms.Term + '%'
```

Comment: Those are both OR not AND

Comment: It finds the columns that contain any of the terms instead of the columns that contain all of the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT      MT.* 
FROM        MyTable AS MT INNER JOIN
            @Terms AS TR ON CHARINDEX(TR.Term, MT.MyColumn) > 0
GROUP BY    MT.MyColumn
HAVING      COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Terms)
```